# add/delete series dynamically/programmatically in dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

lets say dygraph is already showing a chart with few series. Is it possible to add/insert a new series, or delete one existing series dynamically(via javascript)?

I could not find anything like it in examples/documentation.

Answer (score 3):

dygraphs doesn't take responsibility for managing your data. That's up to you.

That being said, you can show/hide series using the [visibility](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#visibility) option.

Comment: I think what Praveen is referring to is the Matlab great feature "hold on". This allows the drawing of one line on top of other lines after the plot data has been loaded. I am as well interested in this feature and I believe is not a data management issue but a visualization issue when you deal with two plots and two separated data source (e.g. two data files). Danvk could you please tell us if reloading a new data set is the only way to add a new line to a plot? thanks a lot and amazing work.

Comment: Indeed, Hold On is great in Matlab, but I believe reloading/replotting the data is the only way to add an additional timeseries in dygraphs.

Answer (score 3):

Keep your data and label arrays somewhere.
When you want to add a new series, pull them up, update with new data and then

```
g.updateOptions({'file':data,'labels':labels});
```

> "data" is the updated data array
>   For this example I am using native data format. For CSV you would edit the original data csv file and update it similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add those later on, however you can plot multiple series with the dygraph.
If you have 2 time series t1 and t2, you can combine them and pass the date to dygraph

```
combined <- cbind(t1, t2)
dygraph(combined)
```